# SQL Server 2008R2: Modifying the partition scheme of a table

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, partition

I have a set of tables that are partitioned on a partition scheme A and now I would like to change to using partition scheme B instead. I've read online articles (such as [this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/01/25/sql-server-2005-database-table-partitioning-tutorial-how-to-horizontal-partition-database-table/)) about doing that but it appears to be quite bothersome.

But it seems like the general way of doing this is to:
1. Drop all foreign keys
2. Drop the cluster primary key
3. Re-add the primary key with the new scheme
4. Re-add all the foreign keys

However, not being too fluent with T-SQL, I am not too sure how to do this dynamically. I'd like to write a script to store all the key settings and re-applying that later without human supervision and that appears to be beyond me at the moment. MSDN is also not very helpful because it's just data overload when I read their documentations.

Is there any resource I can read that'd provide more insight on how to do this? Perhaps some clever method call from a built-in method I don't previously know on SQL Server?

Any input would be appreciated. Thanks